# While loop repeating the same data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, syntax

I am attempting to pull data from my DB with a while loop. 
The code pulls the correct amount of SQL rows, however it repeats the same entry over and over.

I've been fiddling with this code for hours and cant seem to get it to work. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM grow_details";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);

       $grows = array();
       while ($grow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
           $grows[] = $grow;
       } 
       foreach($grows as $grow) {
    ?>
    <div>
        <h2><?php echo $name; ?></h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="datePlanted">Date Planted:</label></td>
                <td><?php echo $datePlanted; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="strain">Strain:</label></td>
                <td><?php echo $strain; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="toMaturity">Days to mature:</label></td>
                <td><?php echo $toMaturity; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="type">Type:</label></td>
                <td><?php echo $type; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="gender">Gender:</label></td>
                <td><?php echo $gender; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="medium">Medium:</label></td>
                <td><?php echo $medium; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php 
        }
?>
```

Outputs:

```
T3
Date Planted:   12/20/2017
Strain:     Kiwi
Days to mature:     50
Type:   ?
Gender:     ?
Medium:     Aero
<br>
T3
Date Planted:   12/20/2017
Strain:     Kiwi
Days to mature:     50
Type:   ?
Gender:     ?
Medium:     Aero
<br>
T3
Date Planted:   12/20/2017
Strain:     Kiwi
Days to mature:     50
Type:   ?
Gender:     ?
Medium:     Aero
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using anything from the array that you're iterating over in the loop. You're just printing the same `$name`, `$datePlanted`, etc. variables each time. `echo $name` should be `echo $grow['name']`, and similar for all the other variables.

Comment: Barmar thank you , I will try this and let you know what I come up with.